# Gnome Shell / Screencast / UPDATE_POINTER_TIME

Tags: gnome-shell, screencasts

System: Ubuntu 18 x64

I use Gnome Shell's built-in screen recorder with shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. It works nice with one exception:

It creates a nice 30 frame output video, but it updates the mouse pointer at every 100ms only, so the pointer is too sloppy and laggy to demonstrate with it any stuff on the screen. See the relevant source code here:

https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/src/shell-recorder.c#L135

This option seems hard coded. My question is, how can I patch my system to change this value to 33 to make the cursor update with every 30 frames?

Looking for this option in my system, I can find it in the following lib:

```
cd /usr/lib/gnome-shell
grep -ir UPDATE_POINTER_TIME
Binary file libgnome-shell.so matches
```

This file can be found in the following package:

```
apt-file search libgnome-shell.so
gnome-shell: /usr/lib/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so
```

But I cannot find a devel package for this file. Nor does gnome-devel contain source code for this lib.

Any idea how I could change this hard coded value? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Devel" packages never contain source code for libraries. They contain files for linking *your own* code to those already-compiled libraries.

To change the source code of an existing compiled file, you're looking for *source packages* from which the regular packages (including -dev ones) are built. This isn't something installable, but instead downloadable using:

```
apt-get source gnome-shell
```

This will download the upstream sources from GNOME, plus the Debian packaging files. With those you can compile and create a new .deb package using `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` and install it with `dpkg -i`.